# password.present? analog Datamapper

Tags: sinatra, datamapper

What is analog in datamapper for .present? method?

I have code from rails app an d wan t to reuse it is Sinatra

ex:

```
  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end
```

in model I ave before save callback

```
before :save, :encrypt_password
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `present?` Method in ActiveSupport is defined as follows:

```
class Object
    def present?
      !blank?
    end

    def blank?
      respond_to?(:empty?) ? empty? : !self
    end
end
```

(Source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F)

You could extend `Object` like that, too. It checks whether the Object is not blank. The method `blank?` itself checks whether the Object responds to `empty?`. This is mostly for strings. If the Object does not respond to `empty?`, the method simply returns `!self`. So `present?` would simply return `self`. Therefore you could also write your code as

```
  def encrypt_password
    if password
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end
```

The only advantage of the `present?` method is, that it does not treat an empty string as present, whereas the second method does.

Comment: Thanks! 
I am new to sinatra and poor experience of developing in ruby.
It works but i was afraid it will let password to be " ", i go around that with validations

Comment: if you are sure to get a string you could also use `unless password.empty?`